# ImportError: cannot import name signature

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I am tying to modify the original `sklearn.CalibrationCV`  to create my won version. The original code has "from .utils.fixes import signature". So I did the following in my version:

```
from sklearn.utils.fixes import signature
```

but got a error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name signature
```

When check the sklearn source code on GitHub. I see the following code inside `fixes.py`:

```
try:
    from inspect import signature
except ImportError:
    from ..externals.funcsigs import signature
```

Then I did `from inspect import signature` directly. Still get "`ImportError: cannot import name signature`"

Besides how to fix this, I am also curious about why the original version can import a module that will be imported from another source? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In python 2, the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module does not have a `signature` method.
- In python 3, the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module does have a `signature` method.

This code is just trying to work with both python 2 and 3.

You may want to use the [`funcsigs`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcsigs) module if you are using python 2, or use `sklearn.externals.funcsigs` directly (for version `sklearn >= 0.17`).

Comment: Thanks. When I tried 'from sklearn.externals.funcsigs import signature' got and message 'ImportError: No module named funcsigs'. Any suggestions?

Comment: you could install the `funcsigs` module ?

Comment: Thanks! dnozay! After installing funcsigs, import signature worked. "from funcsigs import signature"

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't work with the latest version of sklearn.

Please install `funcsigs` directly using

```
pip install funcsigs
```

and use `from funcsigs import signature` instead.