# cannot import name 'signature'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to import mean_squared_error,mean_absolute_error from sklearn but I got this error:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error,mean_absolute_error
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'signature'
```

````
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-38-a17f71596abb> in <module>()
from sklearn.externals.funcsigs import signature

```\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>()

    from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
    from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
    from .base import clone
    from .utils._show_versions import show_versions

    ```\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>()
    ```
    from . import __version__
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT

    _DEFAULT_TAGS = {

    ```\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>()
    ```
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
    assert_all_finite,
    check_random_state, column_or_1d, check_array,

    ```\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <module>()
    ```
    from ..externals import six
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
    from .deprecation import deprecated
    from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning as _DataConversionWarning
    ```
    ImportError: cannot import name 'signature'
````

Comment: You need to post the full error message including traceback. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Related? [ImportError: cannot import name signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34457398/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea edited and also i tried the mentioned thread but still have the same error

Comment: same error occurred when i tried to import auto_arima function from pmdarima after some search there is (public vs not public) issue with functions with _  not sure if this is the right interpretation but let me know if there is a solution.